# Get mysql.user unique id?

Tags: mysql

In order to record the author credentials of a database item operation (such as creation or update operations), I am using the following architecture:

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(id integer not null primary key auto_increment
, Item_data varchar(50) not null
, Item_lastmodified_author_name varchar(50) not null
, Item_lastmodified_author_host varchar(100) not null
, foreign key (Item_lastmodified_author_name) references mysql.user (User)
, foreign key (Item_lastmodified_author_host) references mysql.user (Host)
);
```

Is it not possible to make this easier with a unique mysql.user id reference ?

One MySQL server is used for 3 teams. Each team has its own database. As the MySQL queries will be done from the client side.I don't want a user, member of one team, being able to change anything in another team database.

Am I doing it the right way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your foreign keys won't work the way you think for several reasons:

- The `mysql.user` table is MyISAM, not InnoDB table in current versions of MySQL. Foreign keys are not supported in MyISAM.
- You misunderstand the syntax for a multi-column foreign key. You wouldn't make a separate foreign key to each column, you'd make one foreign key comprised of both columns, referencing the primary key of the target table.
- Even if you could make a foreign key to `mysql.user`, that would allow any team to reference *any* user in that table, not just their own user.

Why not just restrict the privileges of each team's user?

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, 
  EXECUTE ON `team1`.* TO 'team1user'@'%';

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, 
  EXECUTE ON `team2`.* TO 'team2user'@'%';
```

Etc.

Note that they may need other privileges, but you should NOT grant them SUPER privilege, or SHUTDOWN or some others. :-)

---

Re your comment:

MySQL doesn't have any concept of data being "owned" by a particular user. Users have privileges to read or change data, but they don't own it.

You can use columns to store data values that look like user & host, but how would you make sure your teams can't set those values to any value they want? You could design a trigger to do that, but the team could modify the trigger.

Anyway, why would you record the user & host in the table, given that you would already grant privileges so that only the proper team has access to their respective database?

Comment: Ok for privileges, but there is no way to get the user id  as a recorded field? For exemple to keep a knowledge in the database of who is the owner of an item ?